# MySQL stored procedure syntax pain

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a simple Stored procedure that allows me to conduct mass inserts, However I am running into syntactical troubles and unable to figure out where what's going wrong, despite comparing my procedure syntax to existing examples, and it seems to be correct.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE populateUserTable()
 BEGIN
  DECLARE counter int(10);
  SET counter = 1;
 WHILE counter < 101 DO
  INSERT INTO user(userid) values(counter);
  SET counter = counter + 1
 END WHILE;
END
```

Upon running, MYSQL states:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3**

and highlits this guy:

**CREATE PROCEDURE populateUserTable( ) BEGIN DECLARE counter INT( 10 ) ;**

What's up here?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from mysql command line?  Have you changed the delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used

```
DELIMITER $$
```

At the start?

Try

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE populateUserTable()
 BEGIN
   DECLARE counter int(10);
   SET counter = 1;
   WHILE counter < 101 DO
      INSERT INTO user(userid) values(counter);
      SET counter = counter + 1
   END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Because it delimits what constitutes the stored procedure. i.e. stuff between `CREATE` and `END $$`. You do not want it to end at the first `;`